# Статическая библиотека

Tags: c++

Доброго времени суток! Подскажите, пожалуйста:

1. Как объединить 3 объектных файла в статическую библиотеку, используя cl.exe?
2. Будет ли работать вызов функций из этой библиотеки через extern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) вначале, с помощью cl компилируете Ваше исходники. Но нужно делать это с параметром `/c` - это просто сгенерирует `.obj` файлы. Дальше, нужно воспользоваться командой lib, которая сделает `.lib` файл

```
cl f1.cpp /c
cl f2.cpp /c
cl f2.cpp /c
lib.exe /out:f123.lib f1.obj f2.obj f3.obj
```

2) будет все работать также, если бы Вы просто включили эти файлы в проект для компиляции, только нужно помнить, что они уже скомпилированы и не будут реагировать на изменения define и подобное.

Comment: еще вопрос - теперь файл main.cpp, где вызываются extern-ом функции компилировать как обычно - cl main.cpp?

Comment: да, только не нужно забыть прилинковать lib файл.

    cl main.cpp f123.lib